# rollback issue with sqlserver poller - oracle soa 11g

Tags: sql-server-2012, weblogic, jta, oracle-fusion-middleware

I do have a problem in using the DB adapter poller with SQLServer. The below steps describes my setup.

1. DB adapter is configured with SQLServer for polling every 15 seconds.
2. BPEL process receives the polled records and updates another db(oracle)
3. Both oracle and sqlserver (with the required SPs) are configured with XA datasource
4. db adapter datasource is set to xa for both the outbound connections
5. bpel.config.transcation is set to required

product version: 11.1.1.7

"Set XA Transaction Timeout" is checked in datasource transcation tab.

Problem: When the oracle db is not available, I am throwing the rollback exception from BPEL process but the change is committed on sqlserver.

I have enabled the  log configuration for oracle.soa.adapter to FINEST(32) and found the commit is done internally before the process is complete.

the below is the full trace link

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3585747

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you able to use a different integration strategy?
Maybe something based on events, using synchronous web services.

It's known that Bpel Database Adapters (specially polling) contain some bugs and do not perform well under high load.